# No conversion from RGB to YUV

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, yuv

I fail to find an easy-to-use function in any Python library (preferrably PIL) for conversion from RGB to YUV.
Since I have to convert many images, I don't want to implement it myself (would be expensive without LUTs and so on).

When I do the intuitive:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('test.jpeg')
img_yuv = img.convert('YUV')
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: conversion from RGB to YUV not supported
```

Do you know why this is the case?
Is there any efficieint implementation of that in python and maybe even PIL?

I am no computer vision expert but I thought this ocnversion is standard in most of the libraries...

Thanks,

Roman

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could try 'YCbCr' instead of 'YUV', i.e.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('test.jpeg')
img_yuv = img.convert('YCbCr')
```

Comment: This is what I finally did. Bit so far, there seems to be no real solution. Thanks

Comment: I believe `YUV` is actually a term coming from the good old analog times and has no meaning for digital pixel data. People usually actually mean `YCbCr` when they say `YUV` because the term is often misused. See: http://wolfcrow.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-yuv-yiq-ypbpr-and-ycbcr/

Comment: Thanks @jih for the comment. This is what I found out ever since I tried. In my CS courses, people used to have YUV but I see why it's the same as YCbCr.
Thanks for that.

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
import cv2
img_yuv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
```

Comment: But that needs a completely new package (opencv) which I don't want to install just for the conversion.
However, the project is already finished.

Comment: Installing OpenCV just to access the YUV conversion is too time consuming.

Answer (score 5):

I know it may be late, but `scikit-image` has the function [`rgb2yuv`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.rgb2yuv)

```
from PIL import Image
from skimage.color import rgb2yuv

img = Image.open('test.jpeg')
img_yuv = rgb2yuv(img)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to install any additional package, you can just take a look at [skimage source code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/color/colorconv.py#L1573). The following snippet is taken from that github page with some minor changes:

```
# Conversion matrix from rgb to yuv, transpose matrix is used to convert from yuv to rgb
yuv_from_rgb = np.array([[ 0.299     ,  0.587     ,  0.114      ],
                     [-0.14714119, -0.28886916,  0.43601035 ],
                     [ 0.61497538, -0.51496512, -0.10001026 ]])

# Optional. The next two line can be ignored if the image is already in normalized numpy array.
# convert image array to numpy array and normalize it from 0-255 to 0-1 range
new_img = np.asanyarray(your_img)
new_img = dtype.img_as_float(new_img)

# do conversion
yuv_img = new_img.dot(yuv_from_rgb.T.copy())
```